# Mathematica: using mprep in Ubuntu (mprep won't run)

Tags: ubuntu, wolfram-mathematica

I'm using Mathematica 8 in Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail). I'm trying to use the supplied program "mprep", which is used to create applications that link to MathLink. However, whenever I try to run mprep, it gives me the following error:

```
sudo ./mprep addtwo.tm -o addtwotm.c
./mrep: 1: ./mprep: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Here, I'm just trying to compile one of the MathLinkExamples that are supplied with mathematica.

Any suggestions welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Eep, sheepish grin... It turns out that I was using the 64 bit version of mprep, when I had installed the 32 bit version of Ubuntu (by mistake). Happy coding, folks.

Comment: If you solved your problem, then you should accept your own answer.